# How to stop objects from overlapping in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

When I run my code and I press the left arrow, the spaceship is overlapping/multiplying. I want the object to stop duplicating. here's the code:

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((288, 512))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
spaceship = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Anonymous\Downloads\New folder\spaceship.png')
x = 150
y = 495
spaceship_rect = spaceship.get_rect(center=(x, y))
velocity = 10

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= velocity
        spaceship_rect = spaceship.get_rect(center=(x, y))

    screen.blit(spaceship, spaceship_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: cannot reproduce the code, the while loop cannot be empty. please fix your indentation

Comment: you need to update your screen inside your while.

Answer (score 0):

Any object drawn on a surface stays there permanently. Drawing an object only persistently changes the color of some pixels in the surface.
You have to clear the display in ever frame, by [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill), before you draw the scene and update the display:

```py
screen.fill(0)
screen.blit(spaceship, spaceship_rect)
pygame.display.update()
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((288, 512))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
spaceship = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Anonymous\Downloads\New folder\spaceship.png')
x = 150
y = 495
spaceship_rect = spaceship.get_rect(center=(x, y))
velocity = 10

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= velocity
        spaceship_rect = spaceship.get_rect(center=(x, y))

    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(spaceship, spaceship_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```